# Android. How to use android.media.effect package?

Tags: android, video, effects

In Android API livel 14 there was added android.media.effect package. But there is no a lot of documentation about it. I'm interested in applying visual effects to video.

Does anyone have a tutorial or text project which explains ho to apply effects to video? 
Thanks.

Comment: In APIs 16 and 17 there is a sample project ``HelloEffects`` which does showcase some of the effects.

Comment: Hi Maxim Kachinkin, did you get the sample for video effects?